# Trying To Insert xml data in Tally(Units of measure) Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tally

Trying To Insert xml data in Tally(Units of measure) Using C#
I have an harcoded value to which I convert into the xml format , and trying to Insert xml data Into the Tally which having http://localhost:9000.I inserted data to Tally for ledger creation but failed for Units of measure from Inventory Info.

Xml Data :

```
String xmlstc = "";
xmlstc = "<ENVELOPE>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<HEADER>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "</HEADER>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<BODY>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<IMPORTDATA>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<REQUESTDESC>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<STATICVARIABLES><SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Siddharth</SVCURRENTCOMPANY></STATICVARIABLES>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "</REQUESTDESC>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<REQUESTDATA>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF=" + "\"" + "TallyUDF" + "\">\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<UNIT NAME=" + "\"" + "Kg" + "\" Action =" + "\"" + "Create" + "\">\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<NAME>" + "Kg" + "</NAME>\r\n";               
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<ORIGINALNAME>" + "Kilogram" + "</ORIGINALNAME>\r\n";           
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<ISUPDATINGTARGETID>" + "No" + "</ISUPDATINGTARGETID>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<ASORIGINAL>" + "Yes" + "</ASORIGINAL>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<ISGSTEXCLUDED>" + "No" + "</ISGSTEXCLUDED>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<ISSIMPLEUNIT>" + "Yes" + "</ISSIMPLEUNIT>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<ALTERID>" + "1326" + "</ALTERID>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "<DECIMALPLACES>" + "1" + "</DECIMALPLACES>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "</UNIT>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "</TALLYMESSAGE>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "</REQUESTDATA>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "</IMPORTDATA>\r\n";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "</BODY>";
xmlstc = xmlstc + "</ENVELOPE>";
```

Code to send data in Tally (Inventory Info => Units Of measure)

```
String lTallyLocalHost = "http://localhost:9000";
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(lTallyLocalHost);
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = (long)xmlstc.Length;
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
StreamWriter lStrmWritr = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
lStrmWritr.Write(xmlstc);
lStrmWritr.Close();
HttpWebResponse lhttpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream lreceiveStream = lhttpResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader lStreamReader = new StreamReader(lreceiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
lResponseStr = lStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
lhttpResponse.Close();
lStreamReader.Close();
```

Comment: What is the error?  I guess an XML parse error?

Comment: No there is no  parsing Error , I inserted data to ledger and stock group using same xml format .Its not working only for units of Measure ..

Comment: What is not working? What does that mean? Do you get an error? What error? What line of your code fails? What is the exact error message?

Comment: I dont Get any error message .I got data into the datatable from sql server. took a count of rows rotating it using (   for (int i = 0; i < objData.Rows.Count; i++) ).and then i passed data from datatable into xml format between codes..

Comment: I got an error . You cant pass same value to symbol and Formal name from units of measure and you cant pass string and number simultaneously . tally wont accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Tally connector Library](https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyConnector/releases/download/v1.0-net5/TallyConnector.dll) and add reference to your project
Now you can Interact with tally without using XML in your code

To create Unit in Tally use below code

```
Using TallyConnector //Importing TallyConnector Library
using TallyConnector.Models;

Ctally = new Tally();

Unit NewUnit = new Unit();
NewUnit.Name = "Kg";
NewUnit.OriginalName = "Kg";
NewUnit.DecimalPlaces= 1;

await Ctally.PostUnit(NewUnit);// Creates Unit in Tally
```